# Converting "'You have been here for two years and we are going to stay another six months' he said" to reported speech

Tags: reported-speech

How can I convert this to the form of "He said that..."?

> "You have been here for two years and we are going to stay another six months" he said.

My answer:

> He said that *I had been* here for two years and we *were going* to stay another six months.

Is this correct? In particular, are the italicized phrases converted correctly?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask Please read that so you can see how questions should be worded. Thanks.

Comment: This is called reported speech.

Comment: Who'd he say it to? If the subject "you" is me, the reported speech will be different than if the subject "you" is some third party and will be different than if the subject "you" is the person I'm talking to now and reporting the speech to. Also, who is "we"? Am I part of that "we"? Or did the "we" refer to the speaker and some other person or persons? And if so, did "we" include who I am reporting the speech to? Depending on the answers to these questions, there are at least six different ways to write this as reported speech, so please provide more details or this questions is too vague.